# Failed to load module: [Directory/tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs]?

Tags: metasploit

Note: Only for educational purposes.

Basically I am studying CVE-2019-0232, as It says in the cvedetails description its a RCE exploit and a module from rapid 7 has been provide at the bottom of the page for PoC (Proff of Concept)

Rapid 7 says to use module `use exploit/windows/http/tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs` for exploitation. but when I do so I get below error:

> [-] Failed to load module: exploits/windows/http/tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs

I manually went to `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/windows/http` and found that there is no such module, so I thought they might have removed it. I Searched a little bit for any leftover and found another metasploit module for the same CVE from below link and created the module in my current directory (at above dir too) and named it to `tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs.rb`.

But I am still getting above error.

```
$ ls -l 
  .....
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4068 Jul  3 12:38 tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs.rb

msf5 > use ./tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs.rb
[-] Failed to load module: ./tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs

msf5 > use exploit/windows/http/tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs
[-] Failed to load module: exploit/windows/http/tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs
```

CVEDetails:
  https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-0232/

Rapid7: https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/windows/http/tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs

External Module: https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/153506/tomcat_cgi_cmdlineargs.rb.txt

Comment: Off topic -- Voting to migrate to ServerFault, as their list of on-topic questions includes managing workstation configurations to get software working.

Comment: @Ghedipunk No, [sf] deals with running a large enterprise network. This question should go to the Metasploit community forum.